# 2D Arrangment/Optimization Problem

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Okay,

I have a list of angles, call it A. How would I arrange them in a 2D m-by-n grid G such that the distances between each adjacent angle-element (row- and column-wise) is minimized?

G has as many elements as A, or more. I get to pick m and n. Duplicating elements from A is allowed, but every element from A must be used at least once.

Toy Example 1:

```
A = {0, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30}
```

Put them in a 3x3 array:

```
G = {
 {0,  10,  20},
 {10. 20,  30},
 {20, 30,  20}
}
```

Toy Example 2 (list of 5 angles, put them in a 3x2 grid, so have to duplicate 1 element):

```
A = {0, 350, 10, 20, 30}

G = {
 {0,   10, 20},
 {350,  0, 30}
}
```

Hopefully that was clear enough? Let me know if it wasn't....

Comment: What do you mean with the distance between angles? Their difference? Btw, try to format the code in valid Mathematica syntax next time :).

Comment: How about this: Fix $m=1$ and sort the entries of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
A = Sort@{10, 0, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30};

per = Permutations[A];

tot = Total /@ Abs[Differences /@ per];

pos = First@Flatten@Position[tot, Length@A*10 - 10];
```

(for other spacings replace `10` by f.e. `5`).

```
Partition[per[[pos]], 3]
```

> {{0, 10, 20}, {10, 20, 30}, {20, 30, 20}}

For odd `A`:

```
B = Prepend[A, Min@A];
```

and repeat the above steps.